# Where is the best place to create connection strings for multiple environments in Python

Tags: python

I'm decently new to how python is set up and I'm wondering where is the best place to add string variables to use as connection strings for our different servers on our different environments. An example would be creating a connection string in the web.config in ASP.Net. Then having different web.configs in the solutions on our environments. I read up on the configparser but is that the best practice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the options is to use environment variables. Then in your script you can have something like this:

config.py:

```
import os

DB_USER = os.getenv('DB_USERNAME')
# ...
```

Just make sure your environment has all required variables set

Comment: So this will pull the environment variables I create in a windows command line on my server?

Comment: It depends how do you deploy your project. It will not pull any variables, but you have to set them in your environment. If you don't have any automation to deploy then you have to set them manually. But if you use for example Ansible then it can be automated.

Comment: I did some testing and this looks to be the best answer I've learned about this topic so far. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad this helped you!